# Laravel : What to do after installing a php package via composer?

Tags: mongodb, laravel

I installed `mongodb/mongodb` following the docs like this:
docs：https://secure.php.net/manual/zh/mongodb.tutorial.library.php

```
$ composer require mongodb/mongodb
```

Then I use it in a controller,but it has an error:
[image]

Do I need to `use` it in the controller first?
How to find the path of the package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `use MongoDB;` on your controller. Or use:

`new \MongoDB::Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");`

instead of

`MongoDB::Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");`